# How to use Typeahead.js to hide divs

Tags: jquery, html, laravel, typeahead.js

I have a Laravel site, which displays like so:

```
<input class="typeahead" type="text">

<div id="nameName">
    <p>Name Name</p>
</div>

<div id="anotherName">
    <p>Another Name</p>
</div>

<div id="thirdName">
    <p>Third Name</p>
</div>
```

I wish to use Typeahead.js to search the real names and hide the irrelevant divs instantly.

For example, I search for 'thi' and on keyup divs nameName and anotherName are hidden.

I cannot find any examples where this behaviour is demonstrated. How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show all divs back when text value is empty.

```
 $('.typeahead').keyup(function(){
  var txtvalue = this.value;
  txtvalue.length ? $('div').hide().filter(function(){
     return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(txtvalue) > 0;
  }).show() : $('div').show();
});
```

**[Working demo for update](http://jsfiddle.net/9ngk49ep/)**

Comment: he also might want to do a foreach to show all of the divs back again when the input is null (it delets all from list)

Comment: Hiding divs works well, but this is searching the div ids not the actual names - and isn't using Typeahead.js! i.e, searching 'ird' or starting with Caps letter doesn't bring up Third

Comment: Better, thanks. I like the simplicity of it. I'll have a go at integrating it with Typeahead.js

Comment: @MikeThrussell: glad it helps. don't forget to accept the answer if you are satisfied with solution.